# How can I hide "index.php" from the Web Application's URL

Tags: 14.04

I hosted PHP Web Application on UBUNTU 14.04 and it is working good. But I want index.php to be hidden in the Web Application's URL. How should I do it?
For example, I want my web application URL to display like this:
    www.test.com/?.src=ts&.intl=us&.done=http%3A%2F%2Fsite.test.com%2F
I tried following different contents with `.htaccess` but none worked

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

and
    RewriteEngine On
    # index.php -> /
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php

    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://servername/$1 [R=301,L]

I want index.php and directory path to be hidden in the Web Application's URL.   want to convert from www.test.com/index.php/Home/Login to www.test.com/?.src=ts&.intl=us&.done=http%3A%2F%2Fsite.test.‌​‌​com%2F
What should I do to do that?

Comment: what happens when you open the url like this without any modification? `www.test.com/?.src=ts&.intl=us&.done=http%3A%2F%2Fsite.test.com%2F ` What you need should be the default after installing apache and php in Ubuntu

Comment: I want my web URL should be hiden index.php and directory path. I want to convert from www.test.com/index.php/Home/Login  to  www.test.com/?.src=ts&.intl=us&.done=http%3A%2F%2Fsite.test.‌​com%2F   What should I do to do that?